# Checking if two Facebook users are friends or not using Facebook's PHP SDK 4.0 without redirects

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-friends

I'm working on an app and I need to determine if two users are friends.  I am performing this task in an AJAX call so redirects would obviously break my AJAX response.

Every time I check to see if I am friends with someone, it acts like my session is expired and redirects me to the login page.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally wrap my head around this new Facebook SDK.

Here is my solution:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId,$appSecret);

$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
$response = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/' . $userId . '/friends?fields=id,installed,name'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphObject::className())->asArray();
```

This gets the result as an array.  Well, an array of objects anyway.  I hope this helps out anyone else banging their heads.